# Links in localhost

Tags: localhost, xampp, links

I transferred the entire site to Xampp and all the pages are showing the way i designed them.. However, when accessing on localhost from another computer, none of the links work so I can view other pages within my website. I have edited the path several times, including the use of; `http://file:///C:/Xampp/***` and it actually clicked with the `http://`, but still gives a error message saying 'page cant be found'... All the page files are in the same folder as the index and yet its still not being accessed from any other computer.

How can I get the links to work and show the actual page of the file paths I entered?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You have to serve these files from the server. `file:///` opens them directly from the hard disk, kind of bypassing the server. But each computer will read its own disk. Naturally these files don't have to exist on other computers or they are in different paths, so you get a "Not found" error.

XAMPP is a development server. It shouldn't be used to host proper websites. This, together with your description of the problem, suggests that you don't exactly understand what you're doing. I would be glad to point you in the right direction, but you haven't clarified what problem you're trying to solve by setting up this whole server thing.